# Need help with solution of the Dirac equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

$$\left(\vec\sigma \cdot \vec{p} \right)^2=\left(\vec\sigma \cdot \vec{p}\right) \left(\vec\sigma \cdot \vec{p} \right)=\vec{p} \cdot \vec{p}+\mathrm{i}\left(\vec\sigma \cdot \left[ \vec{p} \times \vec{p} \right] \right)=p^2$$
Where does this $\left(\vec\sigma \cdot \left[ \vec{p} \times \vec{p} \right] \right)$ come from? Cause isn't $\sigma^2=\mathbb{I}$? It will really be a great help if someone can point me in the right direction.

It does not explain anything from [here](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/quant.mech/lectures/lecture_7/node1.html).

Comment: This question does not show much research effort; the answer is explicitly at Wikipedia here:  [Relation to dot and cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_to_dot_and_cross_product)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general :
$$
\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{a}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{b}\right)=
\left(\mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{b}\right)\mathrm{I}+i\left[\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)\right]
\tag{01}
$$
since

\begin{align}
\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{a}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{b}\right)&=
\left(a_{1}\sigma_{1}+a_{2}\sigma_{2}+a_{3}\sigma_{3}\right) \left(b_{1}\sigma_{1}+b_{2}\sigma_{2}+b_{3}\sigma_{3}\right)\\
& = 
a_{1}b_{1}\sigma_{1}^{2}+a_{2}b_{2}\sigma_{2}^{2}+a_{3}b_{3}\sigma_{3}^{2}+\\
& \quad \:\:  \left(a_{2}b_{3}-a_{3}b_{2}\right)\sigma_{2}\sigma_{3}+\left(a_{3}b_{1}-a_{1}b_{3}\right)\sigma_{3}\sigma_{1}+ \left(a_{1}b_{2}-a_{2}b_{1}\right)\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}\\
& =\underbrace{\left(a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3}\right)\mathrm{I}}_{\sigma_{1}^{2}\boldsymbol{=}\sigma_{2}^{2}\boldsymbol{=}\sigma_{3}^{2}\boldsymbol{=}\mathrm{I}}+\\
&\quad \underbrace{i\Biggl(\begin{vmatrix}a_{2}&a_{3}\\b_{2}&b_{3}\end{vmatrix} \sigma_{1}  +  \begin{vmatrix}a_{3}&a_{1}\\b_{3}&b_{1}\end{vmatrix}\sigma_{2}+ \begin{vmatrix}a_{1}&a_{2}\\b_{1}&b_{2}\end{vmatrix}\sigma_{3}\Biggr)}_{ \sigma_{2}\sigma_{3}\boldsymbol{=}i\sigma_{1}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\sigma_{3}\sigma_{2}\:,\: \sigma_{3}\sigma_{1}\boldsymbol{=}i\sigma_{2}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\sigma_{1}\sigma_{3}\:,\: \sigma_{1}\sigma_{2} \boldsymbol{=}i\sigma_{3}\boldsymbol{=}\boldsymbol{-}\sigma_{2}\sigma_{1}}\\
&=\left(\mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{b}\right)\mathrm{I}+i\left[\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{b}\right)\right]
\tag{02}      
\end{align}

---

Now, equation (01) has an interpretation in case that $\:\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}\:$ are unit vectors. So let the identity (01) with unit vectors
\begin{equation}
\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{1}\right)=
\left(\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\mathrm{I}-i\left[\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\right], \quad \text{where} \:\: \Vert\mathbf{n}_{1}\Vert=1=\Vert \mathbf{n}_{2}\Vert
\tag{03}
\end{equation}
If the angle between $\:\mathbf{n}_{1},\mathbf{n}_{2}\:$ is $\:\phi\:$ and $\:\mathbf{n}\:$ the unit vector normal to the plane of $\:\mathbf{n}_{1},\mathbf{n}_{2}\:$ 
\begin{align}
\cos\phi & = \mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{2}
\tag{04a}\\
\mathbf{n} & = \dfrac{\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}_{2}}{\Vert\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}_{2}\Vert}= \dfrac{\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}_{2}}{\sin\phi}
\tag{04b}
\end{align}
then the rhs of equation (03) is expressed as
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{Q}=
\left(\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\mathrm{I}-i\left[\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\right]=\cos\left(\dfrac{2\phi}{2}\right)-i\sin\left(\dfrac{2\phi}{2}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}\right)
\tag{05}
\end{equation}
that is a special unitary matrix $\:\mathrm{Q} \in \mathrm{SU(2)}\:$ or a unit quaternion, representation of a rotation around the axis $\:\mathbf{n}\:$ through an angle $\:\theta=2\phi$. Note that the matrix $\:-\mathrm{Q} \in \mathrm{SU(2)}\:$ as expressed by
\begin{equation}
-\mathrm{Q}=
\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi+2\phi}{2}\right)-i\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi+2\phi}{2}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}\right)
\tag{06}
\end{equation}
represents a rotation through $\:\theta'=2\pi+2\phi$, that is the same rotation as $\:+\mathrm{Q}\:$ does.

Now, the special unitary matrix
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R_\jmath}=-i\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n_\jmath}\right)
=\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)-i\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right)\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n_\jmath}\right)
\tag{07}
\end{equation}
represents a rotation  around the axis $\:\mathbf{n_\jmath}\:$ through an angle $\:\pi$, that is a reflection through the axis $\:\mathbf{n_\jmath}$.

So equation (03) is written as

\begin{equation}
\bigl[-i\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\bigr]\bigl[-i\left(\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{1}\right)\bigr]=
-\biggl[\left(\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\mathrm{I}-i\left[\boldsymbol{\sigma}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\left(\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}_{2}\right)\right]\biggr]
\tag{08}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{R_2}\mathrm{R_1}=-\mathrm{Q}
\tag{09}
\end{equation}
meaning that a reflection through an axis $\:\mathbf{n}_1\:$ followed  by a reflection through a second axis $\:\mathbf{n}_2\:$ is a rotation around $\:\mathbf{n}_{1}\boldsymbol{\times}\mathbf{n}_{2}\:$  by an angle $\:2\phi\:$  where $\:\phi\:$ the angle between $\:\mathbf{n}_{1},\mathbf{n}_{2}$ as shown in the Figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is because $\sigma_i \sigma_j=\delta_{ij}+\mathrm{i} \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_{k}$. Look at [this article on Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).