# Prove the Pauli matrices identity $(\vec a\cdot\vec \sigma)(\vec b\cdot\vec \sigma)=(\vec a\cdot \vec b)I+i(\vec a\times\vec b)\cdot\vec\sigma$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I wish to prove the following identity
$$
\Big(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\Big) \left(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{\sigma}\right) = \left(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}\right)I+i \left(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}\right) \cdot \vec{\sigma}
$$

regarding pauli matrices and two arbitrary **vector operators**.
The identity's proof is given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices), and is very straightforward.

However, it relies on the assumption that the element  (matrices) of the vector operator $\vec{b}$ commute with the Pauli matrices.

My question is:
Is the identity only valid under this assumption or am I missing something?

Comment: Related : [Need help with solution of the Dirac equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/300423/)

Comment: For instance $\vec{a}=\vec{J}$ might represent a vector operator representing some angular momentum in three directions ($x,y,z$). This would represent the interaction of electrons with a magnetic impurity in the Kondo model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The identity is not valid in general if $a$ and $b$ are vectors of operators.
You can see it easily trying it with $\vec a=\vec b=\boldsymbol\sigma$.

Noting that $\boldsymbol\sigma\times\boldsymbol\sigma=2i\boldsymbol\sigma$ and  $\boldsymbol\sigma\cdot\boldsymbol\sigma=3 I$ you get for the LHS

$$(3I)(3I)=9I$$
while for the RHS
$$ 3I + i(2i\boldsymbol\sigma)\cdot\boldsymbol\sigma=3I-6 I=-3I. $$
where $I$ the identity.

Comment: thanks. A small question though: Isn't $\boldsymbol\sigma\times\boldsymbol\sigma=0$?

Comment: For example, $(\boldsymbol\sigma\times\boldsymbol\sigma)_1=\boldsymbol\sigma_2 \boldsymbol\sigma_3 - \boldsymbol\sigma_3 \boldsymbol\sigma_2 = YZ - ZY = 2YZ = 2i X = 2i \boldsymbol\sigma_1$.